# JavaFX - How can I display String from 'webEngine createWebEngine(Stage stage)' to Pane in other class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display String from the code below to Pane in other class.

```
public WebEngine helloWebEngine(Stage stage) {

    WebView wv = getWebView();
    webEngine = wv.getEngine();

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.RUNNING) {  
                stage.setTitle(webEngine.getLocation());


                 try {
                      TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                          .newInstance();
                      Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                      transformer.transform(new DOMSource(webEngine.getDocument()),
                          new StreamResult(stringWriter));
                      String xml = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
                      System.out.println(xml);



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    });
    return webEngine;
```

So, there's String 'xml' in the code.
I can print in the console, of course. But I want to display on the pane in another class. I tried using Text object to hold String with setText(xml) and getText() but it didn't work for me, or I used in a wrong way.

Do you have any idea for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in some class, say, `WebViewTransformer` (you can probably choose a better name), add a `StringProperty` to that class and set it from the handler:

```
public class WebViewTransformer {

    private final StringProperty xml = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty xmlProperty() {
        return xml ;
    }

    public final String getXml() {
        return xmlProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setXml(String xml) {
        xmlProperty().set(xml);
    }

    // not really sure why this takes a stage as parameter....
    public WebEngine helloWebEngine(Stage stage) {

        WebView wv = getWebView();
        webEngine = wv.getEngine();

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == Worker.State.RUNNING) {  
                    stage.setTitle(webEngine.getLocation());


                     try {
                          TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                              .newInstance();
                          Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                          StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                          transformer.transform(new DOMSource(webEngine.getDocument()),
                              new StreamResult(stringWriter));
                          String xml = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();


                          setXml(xml);



                        } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        });
        return webEngine;
    }

}
```

Now you just need to do

```
WebViewTransformer transformer = new WebViewTransformer() ;
transformer.xmlProperty().addListener((obs, oldXML, newXML) -> {
    // display newXML wherever you need...
});
WebEngine engine = transformer.helloWebEngine(primaryStage);
```